# How do I sort the /2.2/notifications endpoint?

Tags: support, api-v2.2, sort

I do not find information on the notifications api page. I am looking at this: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/notifications I would like to be able to sort by creations date and other fields. is this end point sortable at all?

Comment: Closely related to https://stackapps.com/a/8332/7653.