# Are the revisions returned by /posts/{ids}/revisions guaranteed to be returned in descending order?

Tags: support, api, api-v2.2, sort, revisions

The [`/posts/{ids}/revisions` method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids) returns all revisions to a post, but it doesn't have the `sort` and `order` parameters most methods have. From some quick tests, e.g. [this one](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids#ids=11227809&filter=!*JxbFHyXanVWpF2L&site=stackoverflow&run=true), I think it always returns them in 'descending' order, i.e. the newest revisions first. But this doesn't seem to be documented somewhere.

Can I rely on this behavior, or is it undefined, and do I need to sort it in the application just to be sure?

Answer (score 2):

I think `creation_date` *is* a default/universal sorting, unless `activity_date` is available. <sup><sub>(But you know what they say happens when you "ASSUME".)<sup>‡</sup></sub></sup>

**Evidence for:**

- Seems like it would be required if paging is going to work well.
- This [post has 753 edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4673436/revisions) ([759 revision entries](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids#pagesize=100&ids=4673436&filter=!*JxbFHyEBcq*hArY&site=stackoverflow&run=true)) and the creation dates are all in descending order.
- This [post has 429 edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3122/revisions) ([502 revision entries](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids#pagesize=100&ids=3122&filter=!*JxbFHyEBcq*hArY&site=meta&run=true)) and it has at least 1 edit of each subtype ([title, body, tag] x [edit, rollback] + suggested edit). The creation dates are all in descending order.
- [Other routes *seem* to sort by `creation_date` although sorting parameters are not supported by the route](https://stackapps.com/a/8196/7653).
- Likewise, [`/events` sorts by `creation_date`, descending](https://stackapps.com/questions/3151/sorting-the-event-stream), despite that being [unmentioned in the livedoc](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/events).
- This [way old answer about API version 1](https://stackapps.com/a/2233/7653), has the lead developer saying:

  > Because sorting by dates is much more common than by name, ordering is descending by default.

**Evidence against:**

- It's not explicitly stated anywhere.
- The various inconsistent behaviors as documented in the unresolved bugs here on Stack Apps. And on Meta Stack Exchange, and on Meta Stack Overflow.

---

<sup><sup>‡</sup> They say that you've made a cost-effective branching decision based on knowledge and experience. And that it in no way precludes you observing-for and reacting-to signs that the assumption was false.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! FWIW, it's [not possible](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/11227809/revisions?sort=creation&order=asc&site=stackoverflow&filter=!*JxbFHyXanVWpF2L) to sort in ascending order (I tried `sort=creation_date` as well).

Comment: @Glorfindel, Yes I forgot to mention that I tried the same thing and also back when I was investigating the `/users/{ids}/reputation-history` route.