# What does it mean when a revision number is missing?

Tags: support, api, revisions

I've noticed in the API docs for [revisions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/revision) that `revision_number` may be absent. Yet all examples, e.g. [/posts/{ids}/revisions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids) include a revision number for all responses.

I have a colleague who swears they've seen missing revision numbers in the wild, but we cannot come up with examples to speculate about what would trigger this.

In what circumstances would a revision number be omitted? What does it signify? And, given that [absent fields should be inferred to be `null`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/absent-fields), if a given revision has no revision number today, might it have one later on, after more revisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several events which count as a revision but do not have a number; only edits (to the body, title or tags) have a revision number. Roughly speaking, everything which is listed on a posts revision history page ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/549/revisions)) counts as a revision. You can compare that with the [API results](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids#ids=549&filter=!9Z(-wlGz(&site=stackoverflow&run=true), and you'll see the revision number is missing for events like

- (un)protecting the question
- closing/reopening the question
- (un)locking the question
- making the question community wiki
- posting a bounty

Those events will never get a revision number in the future (unless the API somehow changes, I guess, but that's not likely) and you'll need [another way](https://stackapps.com/q/8331/34061) to sort them: on creation date or activity date.